# Setting "Server" programmatically with a TFDConnection

Tags: mysql, delphi, firedac

TFDConnection.Params.Server is not a valid published property in Delphi XE7. How can I set the server location programmatically? I have 2 MySQL servers (test and production) that are at different ip's and based on what I am doing in the application, I want to easily switch back and forth between the 2 servers.

Comment: So, what is the problem ? `Close` the connection (or disable the `Active` property), change the `Server` value in the `Params` string list and connect.

Comment: That's what I'm saying ... TFDConnection.Params.Server shows the error: 'TFDConnectionDefParams' does not contain a member named 'server'. Of course I'm actually using the "Name" of the object though, not "TFDConnection".

Comment: You can access it as a string list, e.g. `FDConnection.Params[FDConnection.Params.IndexOfName('Server')] := '...';`. Or you can try (don't have FireDAC by hand), `(FDConnection.Params as TFDPhysMySQLConnectionDefParams).Server := '...'` after adding FireDAC.Phys.MySQL unit (the latter would be safer).

Comment: @TLama: Since `TFDConnectionDefParams` is a `TStringList` descendant, you can use the `TStrings.Values[]` property instead: `FDConnection.Params.Values['Server'] := '...';`

Comment: @Remy, I forgot `Values[]`, thanks! It looked a bit overcomplicated to me... Still, I would say that `(FDConnection.Params as TFDPhysMySQLConnectionDefParams).Server := '...'` should be the preferred way for changing that particular connection definition parameter due to its type safety.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please read the documentation, it tells you exactly how to define a FireDAC connection for MySQL:

[Working with Connections (FireDAC)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Working_with_Connections_(FireDAC))

[Connect to MySQL Server (FireDAC)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Connect_to_MySQL_Server_(FireDAC))

You would specify the DB server as part of a **Connection Definition**:

[Defining Connection (FireDAC)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Defining_Connection_(FireDAC))

Connection Definitions can be defined in an external .ini file, which you can then reference in the [`TFDManager.ConnectionDefFileName`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomManager.ConnectionDefFileName) property, or load dynamically using the [`TFDManager.LoadConnectionDefFile()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomManager.LoadConnectionDefFile) method.

```
[MySQL_Connection_1]
DriverID=MySQL
Server=192.168.1.100
...

[MySQL_Connection_2]
DriverID=MySQL
Server=192.168.1.101
...
```

Or dynamically using the [`TFDManager.ConnectionDefs`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDManager.ConnectionDefs) property:

```
var
  oDef: IFDStanConnectionDef;
begin
  oDef := FDManager.ConnectionDefs.AddConnectionDef;
  oDef.Name := 'MySQL_Connection_1';
  oDef.DriverID := 'MySQL';
  oDef.Server := '192.168.1.100';
  ...
  oDef.Apply;

  oDef := FDManager.ConnectionDefs.AddConnectionDef;
  oDef.Name := 'MySQL_Connection_2';
  oDef.DriverID := 'MySQL';
  oDef.Server := '192.168.1.101';
  ...
  oDef.Apply;
```

```
var
  oParams: TStrings;
begin
  oParams := TStringList.Create;
  oParams.Add('Server=192.168.1.100');
  ...
  FDManager.AddConnectionDef('MySQL_Connection_1', 'MySQL', oParams);

  oParams.Clear;
  oParams.Add('Server=192.168.1.101');
  ...
  FDManager.AddConnectionDef('MySQL_Connection_2', 'MySQL', oParams);
```

Either way, you can then tell `TFDConnection` which Connection Definition to use to reach each database when needed:

```
FDConnection1.ConnectionDefName := 'MySQL_Connection_1';
// or: FDConnection1.ConnectionDefName := 'MySQL_Connection_2';
FDConnection1.Connected := True;
```

Alternatively, you can specify the connection parameters directly in the `TFDConnection.Params` property if you do not want to pre-define separate connection definitions:

```
FDConnection1.DriverName := 'MySQL';
FDConnection1.Params.Clear;
FDConnection1.Params.Add('Server=192.168.1.100');
// or: FDConnection1.Params.Values['Server'] := '192.168.1.100';
...
FDConnection1.Connected := True;
```

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but it's simple to do.

Restating what TLama said in a comment:

The param properties can vary depending on the driver type, so set the driver type to MySQL and then cast the PARAMS as the driver type.
Just do:

```
(Conn1.Params as TFDPhysMySQLConnectionDefParams).Server := '127.0.0.1';
```

This way the compiler can verify the param at compile time.

Comment: True, yet the compiler cannot guarantee that `Params` will be of type `TFDPhysMySQLConnectionDefParams` (the connection object can be connected to a different database type).

Comment: He states he is working with MySQL - not other types.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Add any additional parameters as needed

```
var
oParams: TStrings;
begin
oParams := TStringList.Create;
oParams.Add('Server=' + YourServer);
oParams.Add('Database=' + YourDatabase);
oParams.Add('OSAuthent=Yes');

FDManager.AddConnectionDef('CNX1', 'MSSQL', oParams);
FDConnection.ConnectionDefName := 'CNX1';
FDConnection.Connected := true;
if FDConnection.Connected then
ShowMessage('Connected');
oParams.Free;
```